# Separate JSON files for separate state angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hello everybody I am trying to use yeoman (https://scotch.io/tutorials/internationalization-of-angularjs-applications) They have included JSON file in app.config as below

app.config(function ($translateProvider, DEBUG_MODE, LOCALES) {
    if (DEBUG_MODE) {
      $translateProvider.useMissingTranslationHandlerLog();// warns about missing translates
    }

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
  prefix: 'resources/locale-',
  suffix: '.json'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage(LOCALES.preferredLocale);
$translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
```

});

However I need to have different json files as per the different states

My config is as below

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider , $compileProvider) {

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|javascript):/);

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login/login.html',
    authenticate:false
})
$stateProvider.state('logout', {
    url: '/logout',
    templateUrl: 'templates/logout/logout.html',
    controller: 'LogoutController',
    authenticate:true
})
```

});

So there should be one json file for login and other json for logout which I can use for language translation

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you could have multiple json file for languages but what you are saying bunch of files per language, like for english you need login.json, logout.json etc... So I dont think it is possible even it is possible it s not a good way to do it...

Comment: @Poyraz this is what I exactly wanted separate json files like login.json , logout.json if that would have been possible it would have been good. However if it is not a good way do it then I would avoid it. Many thanks.

Comment: you can have such structure only for reading, but you can define a grunt or gulp task (if you are using) to concant all jsons into one final one so you can achieve what you want...